# Problem adding Azure AD user extension to id token claims

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

I'm attempting to follow the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) to add a user extension to my id token's set of claims, but I can't get it to show up in the token I'm getting.

I've created a user extension in an on-prem AD, and had the value synced with my Azure AD instance.  I verified that the extension was being pushed to Azure AD by looking it up in powershell:

```
PS U:\> Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $UserId

Key                                                  Value
---                                                  -----
odata.metadata                                       https://graph.windows.net/84d1aa3c-****-****-****-*****6b7b6ec/...
odata.type                                           Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
createdDateTime                                      1/31/2019 5:55:52 PM
employeeId
onPremisesDistinguishedName                          CN=Paul LeBlond,OU=Users,OU=@AR,DC=*********,DC=co
userIdentities                                       []
extension_01e6ed59b00**********6ee8e2a025f_pOCCustom customize!
```

According to [this part of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-custom-claims-via-directory-extensions), I need to fully qualify the extension with `extension_<appid>_<extensionName>` and it looks like my sync already did that, although the id shown above doesn't match my appid.  I've tried using the value above, as well as using the appid (with and without dashes) for the middle part, and I've tried just using the extension name (pOCCustom).  None return the claim "extn.POCCustom", which is what I'm expecting.

Here is what the important parts of the application's manifest look like:

```
    "id": "0d18****-****-****-****-****b28f27f",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": null,
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "b4d8****-****-****-****-****234311bd",
...
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
            {
                "name": "extension_01e6ed59b00**********6ee8e2a025f_pOCCustom",
                "source": "user",
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "family_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "given_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
```

I added the family_name and given_name to make sure I was at least close, and those have been included in my id token as expected.

And here is what my idToken looks like when I sign in:

```
{
  "displayableId": "paul@********",
  "name": "Paul LeBlond",
  "identityProvider": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/***/v2.0",
  "userIdentifier": "N2******iNmVj",
  "idToken": {
    "aud": "b4d8****-****-****-****-****234311bd",
    "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/84d1aa3c-****-****-****-*****6b7b6ec/v2.0",
    "iat": 1550157932,
    "nbf": 1550157932,
    "exp": 1550161832,
    "aio": "ATQ******C9bTV+",
    "family_name": "LeBlond",
    "given_name": "Paul",
    "name": "Paul LeBlond",
    "nonce": "a0c13***06",
    "oid": "7ad8**4d75d7e0",
    "preferred_username": "paul@*****",
    "roles": [
      "CanAccess"
    ],
    "sub": "Ko1***K6RMiTrLQAJUI",
    "tid": "84d1aa***e16b7b6ec",
    "uti": "gZ8q****psxrtMAQ",
    "ver": "2.0"
  }
}
```

So I'm getting my family_name and given_name claims, but not my POCCustom claim.  What do I need to do to get that user extension to show up in my id token?

Comment: The extension name in your manifest should be in the format `extension_<appid>_<attributename>` where `<appid>` must match the id of the application requesting the claim. So in your case I suppose it should be `"extension_b4d8****-****-****-****-****234311bd_poCCustom"`

Comment: That's one of the options I tried, and it also did not work.

Comment: I've found there is sometimes a delay with these settings.. So you may have tried something that would have worked :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried changing the token name and waiting a few hours before verifying, but had no luck.  I also added/removed the family_name/given_name to verify that my token was reflecting my latest changes to the manifest each time I tried a different test.